# How do I call a PowerShell command in VBA?

Tags: powershell, ms-access, vba

I have the following command which is tested and working in PowerShell:

```
(new-object -com shell.application).windows() 
    | where {$_.Type  -eq ""HTML Document"" -and $_.LocationURL -match ""$locationurmatch""} 
    | select -last 1 > test918.txt
```

In Microsoft Access, I have the following VBA code where I am trying to execute this PowerShell command, but it does NOT create the text file as hoped:

```
pscmd = "PowerShell.exe (new-object -com shell.application).windows() | where {$_.Type  -eq ""HTML Document"" -and $_.LocationURL -match ""$locationurmatch""} | select -last 1 > test918.txt"
Shell(pscmd)
```

However, the following code does create the output file with the printed text:

```
pscmd = "PowerShell.exe 'test' > thisisatest.txt"
Shell(pscmd)
```

I have printed 'pscmd' to the debugger and copied and pasted the result to PowerShell, and it executes without error. This leads me to believe that the PowerShell command may not be formatted properly for VBA.

Comment: `Shell(pscmd, vbNormalFocus)` is what's executing the PowerShell script and storing the result into `RetVal` which I presume is some local variable you're then testing for an error code to know if the script succeeded or not. Without a `Shell` statement, it can't "run fine" - without a `Shell` statement all you're doing is assigning some string variable with some string literal value.

Comment: The Shell() statement does in fact execute when assigned to a variable. [pscmd = "PowerShell.exe 'asdas' > thisisatest.txt"] does create the file as expected. If I remove the assignment and change the code to Shell(pscmd), I still encounter the same issue. The assignment is required when using vbNormalFocus

Comment: The parens wouldn't be needed if you're not capturing the return value. `pscmd = "foobar"` does not create or execute anything, it's just assigning a string literal. This is getting very confusing. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what the code is that doesn't work?

Comment: Just updated it - I don't believe there's anything wrong with the Shell call as I have tested it with other statements (parens don't make a difference). I'm pretty sure the problem lies within the PowerShell command itself

Comment: FYI the parens don't make a difference because there's only one argument involved. If you look at the actual code in the VBE it's `Shell (pscmd)` not `Shell(pscmd)` (note the space) - that's the VBE telling you that the parens aren't part of the argument list, rather that the expression inside them is going to be evaluated as a value, and then that value will be passed `ByVal` to the invoked procedure - so yeah, it works. But no, it's not *doing nothing*, and it can introduce hard-to-diagnose bugs and, with multiple arguments, compile errors. Avoid extraneous parens in procedure calls.

Comment: I'd think you need to wrap the argument to the `PowerShell.exe` cmd call inside double-quotes, and double them up since this is a string literal as far as VBA is concerned, so `pscmd = "PowerShell.exe ""(new-object -com shell.application).windows() ..."""` - otherwise you're literally just inlining a whole powershell script as a cmd argument.. Alternatively, save the script in a .ps1 file, and pass the filename as an argument. Thanks for editing, it's much clearer now

Comment: I changed my code to the following:

pscmd = "PowerShell.exe ""(new-object -com shell.application).windows() | where {$_.Type  -eq ""HTML Document"" -and $_.LocationURL -match ""$locationurmatch""} | select -last 1 > test918.txt"""

but I am still not getting an output file. I tried creating a .ps1 file but unfortunately I am on a work computer and do not have the proper rights to run it

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix PS and cmd. Replace `> test918.txt` with `| Out-File test918.txt`

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem